# Send user input to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cordova

Right Now i'm building an app using Phonegap/Cordova and jQuerymobile. i have a problem to submit the form of landmark place that take place information, place lat and lon, photo from camera and store the captured image for future use. how store the path/filename of the image into my local database

How can i send the value of user input to the database?

https://jsfiddle.net/qct5j19z/12/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chooseFile").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
  });
  $("input[type=file]").change(function() {
    var file = $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0];
    $("#preview").empty();
    displayAsImage3(file, "preview");


    /* image information 

        $info = $("#info");
        $info.empty();
        if (file && file.name) {
        $info.append("<li>name:<span>" + file.name + "</span></li>");
        }
        if (file && file.type) {
        $info.append("<li>size:<span>" + file.type + " bytes</span></li>");
        }
        if (file && file.size) {
        $info.append("<li>size:<span>" + file.size + " bytes</span></li>");
        }
        if (file && file.lastModifiedDate) {
        $info.append("<li>lastModifiedDate:<span>" + file.lastModifiedDate + " bytes</span></li>");
        }
        $info.listview("refresh");

    */
  });

  $("#locate").click(function() {
    initMap();
  });

//submit user input
   $('#formsubmit').click(function(){
    var pname = $('#pname').val();
    var pinfomation = $('#pinfomation').val();



}); 

});



function displayAsImage3(file, containerid) {
  if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
    var container = document.getElementById(containerid),
      img = document.createElement("img"),
      reader;
    container.appendChild(img);
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theImg) {
      return function(evt) {
        theImg.src = evt.target.result;
      };
    }(img));
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}

var map, infoWindow;
var geocoder;

function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 6
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: 'Your position'
      });
      /*infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Your position');
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);*/
      map.setCenter(pos);


      updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      geocodePosition(pos);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        updateMarkerPosition(e.latLng);
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      });

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }

}

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about? Are you trying to add a record to the database without actually connecting to a backend application?

Comment: @MaciejWilczyński , am sorry if u see the div of result , i remove this part, and yes i want to store the (place name, place information, place type , place image path, place lat &lon) in the database via php